# Constant 429 response from Gmail REST api for particular user

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail-api

We use the Gmail REST api to fetch a user's inbox and to send emails. Starting last night, one of the users on our service had an issue where all of his requests to the Gmail api would return a 429 response with the message "User-rate limit exceeded. Retry at `<time>`".

We understand that in this case, we should just retry the request at the specified `<time>`.

But for this user, it seems even after `<time>` has passed, his requests are still receiving a 429 response (for all the Gmail api's). Even on the first request right after `<time>` has passed.

What could cause this constant 429 status spanning over several hours for the particular user?

Comment: [Implementing exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff) which the client periodically retries a failed request over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors. **Note that daily limits being exceeded may result in these types of errors for multiple hours before the request is accepted**

Comment: We have a QA GMail account that can go days between API calls and is still permanently rate limited.  Exponential backoff doesn't really address this issue.